# Check if all values in array are the same

Tags: php, arrays

I need to check if all values in an array equal the same thing.

For example:

```
$allValues = array(
    'true',
    'true',
    'true',
);
```

If every value in the array equals `'true'` then I want to echo `'all true'`. If any value in the array equals `'false'` then I want to echo `'some false'`

Any idea on how I can do this?

Comment: How did the values get into the array? Why not check them with a simple equality as they're shifted onto the array and obviate the need for any *ex post facto* checking (and thereby, this question). If they come from a database this operation can be handled on the SQL side.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

All values equal the test value:

```
// note, "count(array_flip($allvalues))" is a tricky but very fast way to count the unique values.
// "end($allvalues)" is a way to get an arbitrary value from an array without needing to know a valid array key. For example, assuming $allvalues[0] exists may not be true.
if (count(array_flip($allvalues)) === 1 && end($allvalues) === 'true') {


}
```

or just test for the existence of the thing you don't want:

```
if (in_array('false', $allvalues, true)) {

}
```

Prefer the latter method if you're sure that there's only 2 possible values that could be in the array, as it's much more efficient. But if in doubt, a slow program is better than an incorrect program, so use the first method.

If you can't use the second method, your array is very large, and the contents of the array is *likely* to have more than 1 value (especially if the 2nd value is likely to occur near the beginning of the array), it may be *much* faster to do the following:

```
/**
 * Checks if an array contains at most 1 distinct value.
 * Optionally, restrict what the 1 distinct value is permitted to be via
 * a user supplied testValue.
 *
 * @param array $arr - Array to check
 * @param null $testValue - Optional value to restrict which distinct value the array is permitted to contain.
 * @return bool - false if the array contains more than 1 distinct value, or contains a value other than your supplied testValue.
 * @assert isHomogenous([]) === true
 * @assert isHomogenous([], 2) === true
 * @assert isHomogenous([2]) === true
 * @assert isHomogenous([2, 3]) === false
 * @assert isHomogenous([2, 2]) === true
 * @assert isHomogenous([2, 2], 2) === true
 * @assert isHomogenous([2, 2], 3) === false
 * @assert isHomogenous([2, 3], 3) === false
 * @assert isHomogenous([null, null], null) === true
 */
function isHomogenous(array $arr, $testValue = null) {
    // If they did not pass the 2nd func argument, then we will use an arbitrary value in the $arr (that happens to be the first value).
    // By using func_num_args() to test for this, we can properly support testing for an array filled with nulls, if desired.
    // ie isHomogenous([null, null], null) === true
    $testValue = func_num_args() > 1 ? $testValue : reset($arr);
    foreach ($arr as $val) {
        if ($testValue !== $val) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Note:** Some answers interpret the original question as (1) how to check if all values are the same, while others interpreted it as (2) how to check if all values are the same **and** make sure that value equals the test value. The solution you choose should be mindful of that detail.

My first 2 solutions answered #2. My `isHomogenous()` function answers #1, or #2 if you pass it the 2nd arg.

Comment: why do we need this part? "end($allvalues) === 'true'" Could someone explain please?

Comment: @A.Shulzhenko `end($arr)` is one of many ways to get the value of an arbitrary element in the array. arrays use various indexing schemes, so I can't just assume that say, `$arr[0]`, would exist, because the value might be only found at say `$arr['foo']`

Comment: @Копать_Шо_я_нашел it moves the array pointer to the last item, to make sure it reached the end of the array I assume. Not sure why though

Comment: @goat, `count(array_unique($allvalues)) === 1`- why do you use `===` instead of `==` here ?

Comment: thank you, i just need the count(array_unique($allvalues)) === 1 part

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed using `===` isn't required there, as `==` would also work correctly. But, it's pretty common in php to always use `===` and `!==` unless you specifically want type coercion behavior. So, I just default to using strict comparisons.

Comment: Actually this: if (count(array_unique($yourArray)) <= 1){..} is much faster and doesn't take the actual value in consideration. Just saying.

Comment: Null coalescing in that last snippet would be a sensible, modern touch.

Answer (score 44):

Why not just compare count after calling `array_unique()`?

To check if all elements in an array are the same, should be as simple as:

```
$allValuesAreTheSame = (count(array_unique($allValues, SORT_REGULAR)) === 1);
```

This should work regardless of the type of values in the array.

Update: Added the `SORT_REGULAR` flag to avoid implicit type-casting as pointed out by [Yann Chabot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1887927/yann-chabot)

Comment: `1` will only be returned if there is only one unique value in the input array. The `array_unique()` function "takes an input array and returns a new array without duplicate values."

Comment: No, 1 will be returned if ALL values in the array are the same. If I have array(5,5,5), it will return array(5) and comparison will fail. Your code produces wrong results.

Comment: I have edited my answer to produce the intended result.

Comment: Just a recommandation, if you want it to work with arrays, object and such, add the flag ''sort_regular'' this way: `(count(array_unique($arr, SORT_REGULAR)) === 1);` By default, it compares by string making 1 and '1' be the same element and object are turned into __toString() and arrays won't works. Cheers!

Answer (score 18):

Also, you can condense goat's answer in the event it's not a binary:

```
if (count(array_unique($allvalues)) === 1 && end($allvalues) === 'true') {
   // ...
}
```

to

```
if (array_unique($allvalues) === array('foobar')) { 
   // all values in array are "foobar"
}
```

Answer (score 15):

If your array contains actual booleans (or ints) instead of strings, you could use [`array_sum`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php):

```
$allvalues = array(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE);
if(array_sum($allvalues) == count($allvalues)) {
    echo 'all true';
} else {
    echo 'some false';
}
```

http://codepad.org/FIgomd9X

This works because `TRUE` will be evaluated as  `1`, and `FALSE` as `0`.

Answer (score 5):

You can compare min and max... not the fastest way ;p

```
$homogenous = ( min($array) === max($array) );
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option:

```
function same($arr) {
    return $arr === array_filter($arr, function ($element) use ($arr) {
        return ($element === $arr[0]);
    });
}
```

Usage:

```
same(array(true, true, true)); // => true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$alltrue = 1;
foreach($array as $item) {
    if($item!='true') { $alltrue = 0; }
}
if($alltrue) { echo("all true."); }
else { echo("some false."); }
```

Technically this doesn't test for "some false," it tests for "not all true." But it sounds like you're pretty sure that the only values you'll get are 'true' and 'false'.

Answer (score -1):

Answering my method for people searching in 2023.

```
$arr = [5,5,5,5,5];
$flag = 0;
$firstElement = $arr[0];

if(count($arr) != 0){
    foreach($arr as $val){
        // CHECK IF THE FIRST ELEMENT DIFFERS FROM ANY OTHER ELEMENT IN THE ARRAY
        if($firstElement !== $val){
            // FIRST MISMATCH FOUND. UPDATE FLAG VALUE AND BREAK OUT OF THE LOOP.
            $flag = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
}

if($flag == 0){
   // ALL THE ELEMENTS ARE SAME... DO SOMETHING
}else{
   // ALL THE ELEMENTS ARE NOT SAME... DO SOMETHING
}
```

In an array where all elements are same, it should always be true that all the elements MUST match with the first element of the array. Keeping this logic in mind, we can get the first element of the array and iterate through each element in the array to check for that first element in the loop which does not match with the first element in the array. If found, we will change the flag value and break out of the loop immediately. Else, the loop will continue till it reaches the end. Later, outside the loop, we can use this flag value to determine if all the elements in the array are same or not.

This solution is good for arrays with definite limit of elements (small array). However, I am not sure how good this solution would be for arrays with very large number of elements present considering that we are looping through each and every element to check for the first break even point. Please use this solution at your own convenience and judgement.

Comment: Loose comparisons make this answer less reliable.  @goat's answer already demonstrates how to perform a condition break/return within a loop.

Comment: How is this answer less reliable? If all elements in the array should be same then of couse the first element should match with each and every next element in the array. Even if there is one mismatch then we can conclude that the elements in the array aren't same. For what is asked in the question my answer perfectly solves the issue. Had there been more conditions in the question then of course I would have had added more to the logic.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/jjLGf and I should also mention that this answer is not ready for general use because there will problems when an empty array is passed in.  Ultimately, again, conditionally breaking a loop was already advised in goat's answer.

Comment: It was all about the empty check? I have added it. What else now?

Comment: I have decided that my downvote is justified because, for third time saying this, the advice to conditionally break a loop was already given by goat. My opinion is that this answer is not sufficiently unique in its shared unsights.

Answer (score -3):

```
$x = 0;
foreach ($allvalues as $a) {
   if ($a != $checkvalue) {
      $x = 1;
   }
}

//then check against $x
if ($x != 0) {
   //not all values are the same
}
```